# R - How to perform the same operation on multiple variables

Tags: r, variables, operation

In R, I often times need to do the same operation for a group of variables.

As an example, on my environment I currently have the following of data frames:

```
df_model1
df_model2
df_model3
df_model4
df_model5
```

and I have another data frame called `df_obs`.

What I need to do is to merge each of the `df-model*` data frame to `df_obs`.

What I usually do is something like this:

```
new_df_model1 <- merge(df_obs, df_model1, all=TRUE)
new_df_model2 <- merge(df_obs, df_model2, all=TRUE)
...
```

and so on, which is clearly not very practical.

How can I make this operation more programmatic?

Comment: Instead of merging them you can also combine them in a list `list(df_model1, df_model2, df_model3, df_model4, dfmodel5)` and work with `lapply` to perform the same function on each list element/model

Comment: @Floo0, what would the lapply command look like in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Map` to `merge` `df_obs` and the `df_model` datasets in a `list`.

```
 lst <- Map(`merge`, list(df_obs), 
          mget(paste0('df_model', 1:5)), MoreArgs=list(all=TRUE))
```

If the output datasets in the list needs to be separate data.frame objects in the global environment, we can use `list2env` (but I would prefer to keep it in the list as most of the operations can be done within the list)

```
 names(lst) <- paste('new',paste0('df_model', 1:5), sep="_")
 list2env(lst, envir= .GlobalEnv)
```

Or using `lapply`

```
 lapply(mget(paste0('df_model', 1:5)), merge, x = df_obs, all=TRUE)
```

Comment: This is really close to what I wish, but the output I need are new variables `new_df_model1`, `new_df_model2` and so on, rather than a list. Doable?

Comment: @thiagoveloso That is easy, but I would prefer to keep it in a list without having a lot of variables floating in the global environment

Comment: @thiagoveloso If an expert user like akrun puts all the output in a `list` object there is a reason. It's very bad practice to have different objects polluting your global environment, when you could put them in a list, simplifying in the meantime the process of calling same function on each of them. Learn to use `list`s and you won't regret.

Comment: @nicola I am sure there are many advantages on this, but the output variables will be used to generate taylor diagrams. For this purpose, it would me more complicated If they were a list.

Comment: I can't see a single instance in which what you say is true, in all honesty. It's much more complicated to keep them separated, no matter what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop

```
for(i in 1:5) {
  data <- paste("new_df_model", i, sep = "")
  model <- merge(df_obs, paste("df_model", i, sep = ""), all = TRUE)
  assign(data, model)
}
```